# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. in visualStudio2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight

Hello i have a silverlight application when i tried to run it it will give me error like

Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

same code i have run on other PC then it's working fine

Details of Error

**"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application \nCode: 1001    \nCategory: RuntimeError       \nMessage: AG_E_UNKNOWN_ERROR     \nMethodName:      \n"**

reinstall visual studio but still got this same error.

Can anyone tell me why this happened?

Comment: I also have this issue, the thing causing my issue is when i use the System.Windows.Pivot.dll. I have tried on both VS2012 and VS2010. so its definitely something with the pc itself...

Answer (score 1):

In My case. i moved the referenced dll's out of the folder: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\PivotViewer\Aug10

the error was occuring when i referenced a pivotViewer dll called System.Windows.Pivot

I have a win 7 64 machine.

This seems to resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
This error comes because of Caching of Visual Studio
Delete the Cache.
You can delete the project cache at "Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache", then run "devenv /setup" to build the cache again to see if it helps.
[enter link description here](http://rathodkrunal.blogspot.in/2011/11/visual-studio-2010-error-hresult-efail.html)

Comment: :Thanks for your answer but it's too late

Answer (score 0):

I had separate module on my project, this error occurred in one of the module that has design view (xaml). After numerous tryouts, finally removed error module and re-add it and clean and build resolved the issue.